# Java 7 - Try/finally: how does it know what method to call to cleanup resources in 3rd party API?

Tags: java

In Java 7, instead of

```
        try {
              fos = new FileOutputStream("movies.txt");
              dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
              dos.writeUTF("Java 7 Block Buster");
        } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

              try {
                    fos.close();
                    dos.close();

              } catch (IOException e) {
                    // log the exception
              }
        }
```

You can do this

```
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("movies.txt");
              DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos)) {
              dos.writeUTF("Java 7 Block Buster");
        } catch (IOException e) {
              // log the exception
        }
```

But I am working with a 3rd party API, this API requires that `.close()` be called to cleanup the open resource

```
try (org.pdfclown.files.File file = new org.pdfclown.files.File("movies.pdf")) {
         ...
}
```

How will Java 7 know how to handle a 3rd party API like this?  How will it know what method to call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java 7 introduced ["try-with-resources"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).  The argument in parentheses must implement the [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface, which defines the `close` method.

I'm guessing that the `org.pdfclown.files.File` class implements the `AutoCloseable` interface.

**EDIT**

The [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface, which [`org.pdfclown.files.File`](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/files/File.html) does implement, extends `AutoCloseable` in Java 7.  So it should work in Java 7, because `org.pdfclown.files.File` does implement `AutoCloseable`, even though it does so indirectly.

Comment: You were so close! `org.pdfclown.files.File` implements `java.io.Closable` which (in Java 7) extends `java.lang.AutoCloseable`

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko it does, see my comment above.

Answer (score 6):

It is going to work well if your 3rd party class implements [AutoClosable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface

I have checked out `pdfclown` source [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/clown/code/108/tree/trunk/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/files/File.java) and [here](https://github.com/owq/pdfclown-mod/blob/master/src/org/pdfclown/files/File.java) but it seems like it does not implement `AutoClosable`

Here is the important part from the `File.java` source:

```
public final class File
  implements Closeable
```

**But**, as mentioned in other answers and comments,  [Closable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) extends [AutoClosable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)!

Comment: `Closable` extends `AutoCloseable`

Answer (score 3):

In java 7 the compiler knows that any class that implements AutoCloseable and is declared as part of a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement, to invoke the close method as part of a finally block.